# Can this code be optimize

Tags: apex

The below code is working as expected but can this code be optimized further? and  I'm using three different `for loops` in order to make this working.

I'm trying to find out if the Candidate has attachment associated with the record so each candidate record should associate with one or more attachment.

```
set<Id> setC = new set<Id> ();
//List<Candidate__c> canAttachList = [SELECT id,name (SELECT Id,Name FROM Attachments) FROM Candidate__c WHERE Employee__c ='XXXXX'];
List<Candidate__c> canAttachList = [SELECT id,name FROM Candidate__c WHERE Employee__c ='XXXXX'];


for(Candidate__c c: canAttachList)
{
  setC.add(c.Id);
}
map<Id, Attachment> mapAttach = new map<Id, Attachment>([SELECT Id,ParentId,Name FROM Attachment WHERE ParentId IN : setC ]);

for(Id c : mapAttach.keySet())
{ 
    for(Id d : setC)
    {
        if(mapAttach.get(c).ParentId == d) {
            system.debug('attachment exists');
        }
        else {
            system.debug('no attachment presents');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use query like

```
map<id,Candidate__c>  canAttachMap = new map<id,Candidate__c>([SELECT id,name, (select id from attachments) 
FROM Candidate__c WHERE Employee__c ='XXXXX']);
```

if you know Candidate ID  in your code, to check if he has an attachment:

```
system.debug(canAttachMap.get('XXXXX').attachments.size()>0);
```

output is True/False.

Now to show results:

```
for(Candidate__c candidate:canAttachMap.values())
{
    integer attCounter = canAttachMap.get(ca.id).attachments.size();
    system.debug(candidate.Name + 
    (attCounter > 0 ? ' :
    '+attCounter+' attachment(s) exist.' : 
    ' : no attachment present.'));
}
```

EDIT: renamed list to map. was bad variable name.

Answer (score 3):

Use a subquery

```
for(Candidate__c c : [SELECT id, name, (Select ID From Attachments) FROM Candidate__c WHERE Employee__c ='XXXXX'])
{ 
    if(!c.Attachments.isEmpty()) {
        system.debug('attachment exists');
    }
    else {
        system.debug('no attachment presents');
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there way I can get the which candidate has not have attachment? I have tested and if I have two candidate one has attachment and another does not then i want to know which candidate has attachment and which is not.... i have also noticed that its not doing in my code as well.

Comment: Is this an ongoing need? If so use a trigger on attachment to evaluate / set a flag on the candidate when an attachment is inserted or deleted. You can also write a quick batch process to update existing candidate records.